# Can SQL Server and Mongo be used together?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, nosql

We have a large news-oriented site that has high web traffic. The architecture is your often seen DB - Repo Layer - Services Layer - Asp.Net MVC. The problem that we've been seeing is around read performance. It turns out that all this DDD domain object stuff is great, in theory, for business rules, but has made life harder when it comes to optimizing read performance.

As a solution, I'm considering something entirely new (for us): using noSQL. I'd like to use a noSQL database for data being presented on our website. We can't get rid of our SQL Server (at least not anytime soon), but it seems to me that a practical step would be to use Mongo as a query database for all new development.

My question is whether it is possible to use SQL Server as your database of record and Mongo as your query database together and if so, what technology/technique would you use to update updates? I'd like Mongo to be refreshed ever 15 minutes.

Comment: This MIGHT be a question for programmers.stackexchange.com, but I'm going to be interested in the answers since we are looking at doing the same thing.

Comment: Well, I think *obviously* this is possible - the real question here is whether there's tools or frameworks that can make it easier to use MongoDB as a read-cache for SQL Server.

Comment: Added to stackexchange at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/125980/can-sql-server-and-mongo-be-used-together

Comment: I think using a real data cache will work better than to fake one with mongodb.

Comment: Maybe a cache layer with CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation)?

Comment: As I understand it, nCQRS uses RavenDB, a different noSQL database. Switching over entirely to nCQRS is too big a change, but I want to follow the same CUD separate from R separation.

Comment: What I mean is, using providers that read from the cache instead directly from DB.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest to take a look into [cqrs](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) (*Command Query Responsibility Segregation*) pattern that was initially introduced by [Greg Young](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/). Also you can read [here](http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/3/23/dddd-cqrs-and-other-enterprise-development-buzz-words.html).

This approach involve to have two databases: read and write. Write database is used as primary write store and read - database for querying. Read database can have denormalized data. For example if you have article you can embed author information in it as well for quick display on ui. And in general nosql database good fit for read storage.

In your case primary normalized database can be in sql and read database can be in mongodb.

In general this approach good fit for high traffic systems. There is open source implementation of it -- [ncqrs](https://github.com/ncqrs/ncqrs).

Also this approach in [roadmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/practices/bb232643#8) of microsoft for 2012 year.

from me: I am using this approach more than one year and giving to it my personal vote up.

Comment: CQRS is what I'm trying to do, but am having difficulty understanding how you'd move towards that while still working with an existing legacy system. nCQRS seems like it would require an enormous rewrite. I'm trying to begin with something simple: create a read-only MongoDB and use it for new client side pages. 

As Udi says ". . .  CQRS is an approach, a mind-set – not a cookie cutter solution."

Comment: @John: Yea, Udi Dahan rights as usual. Apply cqrs means a enormous rewriting, but lead to a lot of benefits in the future. Not only performance improvements, scalability but to simplifying and logical separation of application code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to a database like MariaDB Enterprise (on-prem or in the cloud through SkySQL) could be an interesting option to evaluate. MariaDB has multiple pluggable, purpose-built storage engines configured per table and with cross-engine join support (joining tables that use different storage engines). Some (but not all) of these engines are:

- **ColumnStore**: For big data and analytics. This is equivalent to having an index on every column of the table but without the hassle of having to deal with indexes. It scales horizontally supporting ad-hoc queries on hundreds of billions of rows in real time.
- **Aria**: For read-heavy workloads that don't need transactional capabilities but where read performance is critical (for example, shopping carts, reviews, ratings).
- **MyRocks**: For write-heavy workloads that need better compression and less write amplification than other storage engines or databases.
- **InnoDB**: What you need 99% of the time. It supports compression, encryption, transactions, instant schema changes, multi-primary clustering with synchronous replication, and more.
- **MEMORY**: For storing data in memory instead of disk. Ideal for read-only caches, and temporary data.
- **CONNECT**: enables MariaDB to access external local or remote data (MED). This is done by defining tables based on different data types, in particular files in various formats, data extracted from other DBMS or products (such as Excel or MongoDB) via ODBC or JDBC, or data retrieved from the environment (for example DIR, WMI, and MAC tables)
- **Spider**: Supports partitioning and xa transactions, and allows tables of different MariaDB instances to be handled as if they were on the same instance.

Here you find advice on how to choose the right storage engine: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/choosing-the-right-storage-engine/

There is also MariaDB Xpand which almost linearly scales reads and writes while keeping ACID compliance, and MaxScale, a database proxy that enables automatic failover, read-write splitting, transparent masking, exporting and importing database events to and from Kafka (CDC), and even use MariaDB as if it was a MongoDB database (you can connect an application that uses MongoDB drivers and store the data in MariaDB instead of MongoDB itself which allows you to join data from MongoDB apps with data in relational tables using a single SQL sentence).